# VB.NET exception handling for something that returns a data set instead of a string

Tags: vb.net, types, exception, dataset

My program is throwing an error I should handle. But I cannot return a string message because the it is a function that returns a dataset:

```
Public Function getUserInfo(ByValue testUserIdAs String) As DataSet
    Dim dsUseInfo As DataSet = New DataSet()
    Try
        Dim objTestWs As New TestWebService.UserMaintenanceSoapClient
        dsUseInfo = objTestWs.dsGetUserInfo(TestOU, PAC, paramUserID)
        Return (dsUseInfo)
    Catch ex As Exception

        ' TEST FIX ERROR HANDLING -LIWM Please search how to return custom error. I want to return "userid already exists"
        Throw
    End Try
```

I was thinking of putting in:

```
If error
then return "Error Message"
```

But I can't return it as type string.

Comment: You're throwing an exception in your catch block, so you won't be returning the dataset.  Simply include the error message you want when you throw the exception, e.g. `throw new Exception("User not found");`.  Not the most elegant solution, but it will get you what you want.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you don't really know what to do with the exception in `getUserInfo` and just want to pass it on to the outer function.

Well, here's the great thing about exceptions: *They are passed on automatically!* There's nothing you need to do, and, in particular, you do not need to use the return value of the function for that. Just don't catch the exception *until you know what to do with it*.

---

For example, in your case, just handle the error in the *calling* function instead:

- Remove the error handling code from the called function:

  ```
  Public Function getUserInfo(ByValue testUserIdAs String) As DataSet
      Dim objTestWs As New TestWebService.UserMaintenanceSoapClient
      Return objTestWs.dsGetUserInfo(TestOU, PAC, paramUserID)
  End Function
  ```
- and add it to the calling function, i.e., replace

  ```
  ...
  Dim dsUserInfo As DataSet
  dsUserInfo = getUserInfo()
  ...
  ```

  with

  ```
  ...
  Dim dsUserInfo As DataSet
  Try
      dsUserInfo = getUserInfo()
  Catch ex As Exception
      ' Do whatever you want to do in case of an error here
      MsgBox("Could not get User Info: " & ex.Message)
      Return
  End Try
  ...
  ```

---

One you are familiar with this technique, you can go on to more advanced topics like throwing your own exception, like @Justin suggested. Just make sure to include information about the *original cause of the error* in your own exception, for example, by copying parts of `ex.Message` into your own exception message and setting the `innerException` property.

Comment: It can be better to catch/throw a custom if he's potentially catching one of many exceptions in the calling function.

Comment: @JustinEdwards: Yes, could be useful, but when done improperly this can lead to information about the original exception (and, thus, the original cause of the error) to be lost.

Comment: In that case, it seems like throwing the message with the initial exception as the inner exception might be the way to go.

Comment: @JustinEdwards: Indeed. I've extended my answer, thanks for your feedback!

Comment: this will result in dangling / lost exceptions just because the dev forgot about them - one of the worst mistakes one could do, additionally, one will be forced to try/catch everywhere - which results in unreadable code.

Comment: @specializt: I'm not sure I get your point. Usually, you have a catch-all exception handler directly below your UI (and *only there*, ideally, your UI library [has a specialized method for that](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.dispatcherunhandledexception.aspx)), where you log and show unexpected errors.

Answer (score 0):

You could throw a generic exception:

```
Public Function getUserInfo(ByValue testUserIdAs String) As DataSet
    Dim dsUseInfo As DataSet = New DataSet()
    Try
        Dim objTestWs As New TestWebService.UserMaintenanceSoapClient
        dsUseInfo = objTestWs.dsGetUserInfo(TestOU, PAC, paramUserID)
        Return (dsUseInfo)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw New Exception("Custom message", ex)
    End Try
```

This will set the message on the exception you catch up the call stack to be "Custom Message" with an [inner exception](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.innerexception.aspx) that contains the original exception which was thrown.

Or you could create a custom exception(by inheriting from System.Exception) elsewhere if you want to throw a more expressively named exception(and so you don't have to catch all exceptions when you want to catch this custom type).

```
Public Class UserInfoNotFoundException
    Inherits System.Exception

    Public Sub New()
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(message As String)
        MyBase.New(message)
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(message As String, innerException As Exception)
        MyBase.New(message, innerException)
    End Sub
End Class
```

You could then, for example, throw a UserInfoNotFoundException.

Answer (score 0):

I would change the whole approach to exceptions and errors:

- Create a new assembly (project) and reference it in your application
- Declare new shared events which accept your personal datatype (referenced assembly)
- Declare at least one shared function (referenced assembly) which does a RaiseEvent on your new events
- Add handlers (main application) for your shared events in which you react accordingly
- Call your function from within the main application,
  passing your own parameters whenever you need to throw errors /
  exceptions

This way you circumvent many programming mistakes **and** centralize error and exception-handling.

```vb
Public Module IDENTIFIERS

    Public Enum EvtMsg
        ERR_MYERR
        ERR_MYERR2
    End Enum

    Public Enum EvtClass
        EXCEPTION
        ERR
    End Enum
End Module

Public Class Events

    Shared Event Err(ByVal code As EvtMsg)
    Shared Event Exception(ByRef iEx As Exception)

    Public Shared Sub Raise(ByVal iEvtClass As EvtClass, ByVal iMsg As EvtMsg, Optional ByRef iEx As Exception = Nothing)
        If Not [Enum].IsDefined(GetType(EvtClass), iEvtClass) Then
            Dim ex As New ArgumentOutOfRangeException("unbekannte Event-Klasse '" & iEvtClass.ToString & "' übergeben", "iEvtClass")
            RaiseEvent Exception(ex)
        End If
        If Not [Enum].IsDefined(GetType(EvtMsg), iMsg) Then
            Dim ex As New ArgumentOutOfRangeException("unbekannte Event-Msg '" & iMsg.ToString & "' übergeben", "iMsg")
            RaiseEvent Exception(ex)
        End If

        Select Case iEvtClass
            Case EvtClass.ERR
                RaiseEvent Err(iMsg)
            Case EvtClass.EXCEPTION
                If iEx IsNot Nothing Then
                    RaiseEvent Exception(iEx)
                Else
                    Dim ex As New MissingFieldException("Raise() ohne Exception aufgerufen, iMsg : " & iMsg & "EvtClass : " & iEvtClass.ToString(), "iEx")
                    RaiseEvent Exception(ex)
                End If
        End Select
    End Sub

End Class
```

And now you can easily use these error-handlers in any assembly which references your error-assembly:

### Constructor

```vb
AddHandler Events.Err, AddressOf Err
AddHandler Events.Exception, AddressOf Except
```

### Class-body

```vb
Private Sub Except(ByRef iEx As Exception)
    'do your stuff here
End Sub

Private Sub Err(ByVal Err As EvtMsg)
    'do your stuff here
End Sub
```